# Traduction de « something is going down »

Tags: traduction, anglais, argot

En anglais argot on peut dire « A fight is going down » qui veut dire qu'une bagarre se passe mais qui est (je trouve) plus fort que juste « se passer ».  On peut utiliser « to go down » avec plus de choses qu'une bagarre.

Existe-t-il une expression équivalente en français?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dans ce cas précis :

> Il va y avoir du grabuge.

ou

> Ça va saigner.

(avec une pointe d'exagération quand même).
Et il est possible de réutiliser ces tournures (*il va y avoir…*, *ça va…*) dans plein d'autres cas.

Answer (score 3):

Aux propositions de Stéphane, j'ajouterais celle-ci :

> *A fight is going down* / **Ça va morfler**.

(par analogie avec la forme personnelle *You're going down!* / **Tu vas morfler !**)

---

Citons aussi (plus grossier, soit, mais très employé quand le contexte l'autorise) :

> **Ça va chier!**

Answer (score 3):

Pour avoir une expression aussi polyvalente, je verrais bien *Il y a du* X *dans l'air* ou *ça sent le* X *(par ici)*. Par exemple

> Il y a de la bagarre dans l'air.

mais aussi

> Ça sent le changement de variable par ici.

et même

> Il y a du théorème de Stokes dans l'air.

Answer (score 3):

Pour rejoindre le sens expliqué par Evpok, ça serait aussi traduisible aussi par

> Ca sent la bagarre

Cependant, il me semblait que l'expression *to go down* n'impliquait pas de doute quand à l'exécution de l'action. *A fight is going down* signifie *Il y a une bagarre* et non *Il va y avoir une bagarre*.

Voir:

- le sens 8. dans le [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/go_down).
- le sens 5. dans le [freedictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/go+down)

Comment: Tu as raison que *A fight is going down* veut dire *Il y a* et pas *Il va y avoir* et j'ai changé ma question.